# Can I use Arduino for a cubesat?

Tags: cubesat

we are building a cubesat and we have considered using an arduino as the computer. However I'm not sure if that is smart. I mean will the arduino get damaged in some sort? 
Is arduino suitable to do cubesats?
Is it effective or will we face problems?
And is there better alternative?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Space Stack Exchange. If you don't get what you wanted from the answers to the previous question then you could try reframing your question so that its clear what you are looking for that isn't already answered.